# Magento 2 customer dashboard, custom block, sub-navigation

Tags: magento2, php, customer, navigation, dashboard

I understand how to remove or add a navigation link in customer dashboard on magento2

Need to know how can i create submenus, or add a static text in the sidebar navigations

eg. Following is the current sidebar navigation

```
My Profile
Order History
Wishlist
```

I need to make the following changes

```
*Customer Name / Customer Company Name*
--My Profile
----My Addresses
----Change Password
--Order History
--Wishlist
```

Comment: At the moment i haven't found anything for this.. so i am just removing the $block->getChildHtml(); and add static content in the Magento_Customer/templates/account/navigation.phtml